# C# String Interpolation and the Conditional Operator

Tags: c#, string, conditional-statements, string-interpolation

How I can return null in the string if my {condition} is false. I'm using string interpolation with the conditional operator.

`string returnURL = $"{ condition ? (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationURL"]}/my-page/{trip?.TripUId }) : null"`

Comment: add parenthesis: `$"{(condition ? ... : ...)}"`

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Do you want `returnURL` itself to be null if `condition` is false? A [mcve] with sample input and output would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Send the error message.

Comment: (I suspect you should just use the conditional operator *outside* the interpolated string literal: `string returnUrl = condition ? $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationURL"]}/my-page{trip?.TripUid}" : null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
bool flag = true;
string returnUrl = flag ? $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationURL"]}/my-page{trip?.TripUid}" : null;
```